# Why does my .ipynb file works but same code in .py does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, jupyter

I am building a project in Python using VSC I am trying to fetch data using API and store it into a sqlite3 database (can use only this database) when I am running this code in jupyter Python notebook format it is working and able to upload the data successfully to the database, where as same code in normal Python file is not working.

This is my ipynb file

```py
# %%
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import eikon as ek 
import json
import datetime as dt
import sqlite3 as sql


# %%
ek.set_app_key('45a807bae5a6416c8aaf5be32d64c3be68e5e623')

# %%
with open('ProductDataJson2.json', 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# %%
fields_array=['OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME']

# %%
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['RIC(i)','Category']+fields_array)

# %%
def geteikondata_daily(ric,fields,start_date,end_date):
    
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    start_date1=start_date
    end_date1=end_date
    while True:
        try:
            tmp_df=ek.get_timeseries(ric, interval = 'daily', start_date = start_date1, \
                                   end_date = end_date1, fields=fields)
            df=pd.concat([tmp_df,df])
            end_date1=df.index[0]-dt.timedelta(microseconds=1)
            end_date1=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.datetime.timestamp(end_date1))
        except ek.EikonError as err:
           print(err)
           break
    return df

# %%
for category, product_list in data.items():
    for product in product_list:
        ric=product['RIC']
        fields=['OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE']
        end_date = dt.datetime.utcnow()
        start_date = end_date - dt.timedelta(days=5)
        ric_symbols=[f"{ric}c{i}" for i in range(1,2)]
        for ric_symbol in ric_symbols:
            retrived_data=geteikondata_daily(ric_symbol,fields,start_date,end_date)
            if not retrived_data.empty:
                retrived_data=retrived_data.reindex(columns=fields_array,fill_value=pd.NA)
                retrived_data=retrived_data.reset_index()
                retrived_data['RIC(i)']=ric_symbol
                retrived_data['Category']= category
                df=pd.concat([df,retrived_data],ignore_index=True)
                print(df)
            else:
                print(f"Data for {ric_symbol} is empty, skipping .....")

# %%
conn = sql.connect('my_database.db')
df.to_sql('my_table', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Uploads data to database correctly

[image: here's the db]

but when I try this

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import eikon as ek 
import json
import datetime as dt
import sqlite3  as sql

with open('ProductDataJson2.json', 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

fields_array=['OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME']

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['RIC(i)','Category']+fields_array)

def geteikondata_daily(ric,fields,start_date,end_date):
    
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    start_date1=start_date
    end_date1=end_date
    while True:
        try:
            tmp_df=ek.get_timeseries(ric, interval = 'daily', start_date = start_date1,end_date = end_date1, fields=fields)
            df=pd.concat([tmp_df,df])
            end_date1=df.index[0]-dt.timedelta(microseconds=1)
            end_date1=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.datetime.timestamp(end_date1))
        except ek.EikonError as err:
           print(err)
           break
    return df

for category, product_list in data.items():
    for product in product_list:
        ric=product['RIC']
        fields=['OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE']
        end_date = dt.datetime.utcnow()
        start_date = end_date - dt.timedelta(days=3)
        ric_symbols=[f"{ric}c{i}" for i in range(1,3)]
        for ric_symbol in ric_symbols:
            retrived_data=geteikondata_daily(ric_symbol,fields,start_date,end_date)
            if not retrived_data.empty:
                retrived_data=retrived_data.reindex(columns=fields_array,fill_value=pd.NA)
                retrived_data=retrived_data.reset_index()
                retrived_data['RIC(i)']=ric_symbol
                retrived_data['Category']= category
                df=pd.concat([df,retrived_data],ignore_index=True)
                print(df)
            else:
                print(f"Data for {ric_symbol} is empty, skipping .....")

conn = sql.connect('my_database.db')
df.to_sql('my_table', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Project 3 - Market Movement\Back\test.py", line 41, in <module>
    retrived_data=geteikondata_daily(ric_symbol,fields,start_date,end_date)
  File "c:\Users\Project 3 - Market Movement\Back\test.py", line 26, in geteikondata_daily
    end_date1=df.index[0]-dt.timedelta(microseconds=1)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5320, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I tried altering the column names, column types, rearranging the columns trying and matching the datatypes but it still gave this error.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: my hunch is that itis the path (since i have had this error many times). However, show the error message, so that we can be sure....

Comment: error may suggests that you work with different data - which has different size (or is empty) - and it can find some column or row. First check what exactly you have in data You could use `print()` to to check it.

Comment: @furas i have tried checking the data, data is completely identical and not empty. both codes are operating on same dataset

Comment: You forgot `ek.set_app_key()` in your python version. There are also some slight differences in parameter values for `start_date` and `ric_symbols`

Comment: you can use `print()` check results in every step of `py` - and compare with results in every step of `ipynb` -  especially `print(df.index)`, `print( len(df.index) )` because this element makes problem with `[0]`

Comment: Focus on why `df.index[0]` has problems.  Why `df.index` size 0?  Why does `df` have 0 rows?  Is `tmp_df` empty?